# Cannot load custom fonts in Postscript Type 1 format

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts

I have no problem to load custom fonts in formats of .otf or .ttf.

But my client sent me a DIN font suite in Postscript Type 1, which has no file name suffix. What I did:
1. added font file to Xcode 4. Xcode 4 can generate font preview
2. revised .plist file, by inserting rows to "Fonts provided by application"
3. use [UIFont fontWithName: size:] method to load custom font

what I received: upon app starts, a log message was generated in console saying ": FT_Open_Face failed: error 85."

Please guide me, thank you!

Comment: How did you resolve the problem?

Comment: i asked my client to find .ttf/otf format fonts instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's only possible to use .ttf and .otf custom fonts for this case.

Comment: its been a few years, any updates on this as im facing the same issue.